# jQuery find selector problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, fancybox

I got such code:

```
$('.mainp').find('A[href$=jpg]','A[href$=jpeg]','A[href$=gif]','A[href$=png]').fancybox();
```

And it works only for .jpg files. When I change it to:

```
$('.mainp').find('A[href$=png]').fancybox();
```

It works for .png files. So what I'm doing wrong, that fancybox() is not working with all type of files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commas belong in the string, I don't think `find` can take many parameters.

```
$('.mainp').find('A[href$=jpg], A[href$=png]').fancybox();
```

See also: [Selectors/Multiple](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple)